# Play a wav file retrieved from a database on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I have alot of wav files stored in sqlite3, but when I retrieve one of them, I can't play it. The retrieve code is

NSData *soundData = (NSDATA *)sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 0);
mPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:soundData error:&error];

The data is stored as binary and it's there when I search for it using sqlite3.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. Never mind. I just compressed the data more and it works fine now. Seems the number of files is not as important as their size afterall.